# Return "No Data Found" in search functionality in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble with React js. I am implementing search functionality. Everything is good but I want to show if the term entered in the search bar is not available. It should show "No Data Found". I have also attached the screenshot.

Search Component

```
const UserDetails = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setPosts(data.results));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="Navbar">
        <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="" />
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
          }}
          placeholder="Search User.."
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className="card">
        {posts.length > 0 ? (
          posts
            .filter((val) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return val;
              } else if (
                val.name.first
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                val.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return val;
              }
            })
            .map((post, index) => <Userdetail key={index} post={post} />)
        ) : (
          <div className="loading">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p className="loading-data">Loading Data...</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserDetails;
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyicC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if `posts` has values, and if it doesn't it should show `loading` div. This is the place where you should add "No data found" and for the loading you should set state to indicate loading status.

I have modified your code a bit

```js
const UserDetails = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false) // loading state

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true); // loading started
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts(data.results);
        setLoading(false); // loading stopped
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setLoading(false); // loading stopped
        console.log(e);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="Navbar">
        <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="" />
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
          }}
          placeholder="Search User.."
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className="card">
        {loading ? ( // loading state
          <div className="loading">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p className="loading-data">No data</p>
          </div>
        ) : posts.length > 0 ? (
          posts
            .filter((val) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return val;
              } else if (
                val.name.first
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                val.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return val;
              }
            })
            .map((post, index) => <Userdetail key={index} post={post} />)
        ) : (
          <p>No data found!</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserDetails;
```

Comment: I appreciate this. But still, it is not showing "No Data Found".

Comment: You obviously have values in `posts` array, because that's the only condition for it to show search results

Comment: can't we add one more conditional statement?

Comment: Well, only if you don't have anything in `posts` array, you will see that message. What do you seen now?

Comment: it is showing nothing. It's blank.

Comment: Remove entire `useEffect` block and see if you're getting that message